# NTFS allow Read/Write/Modify, but not Copy

Tags: security, filesystems, file-sharing, ntfs

Is it possible to allow users to modify and read files/folders but not copy them to other locations?

Problem is I have a folder that users need to read and modify files in, but I don't want them copying them to their local computer. I know they could SAVE AS to their local computer but with the file type I'm trying to protect it wouldn't work that way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can read it they can copy it ... Depending on what the file is you might be able to do some sort of DRM like [Windows Rights Managemnet](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologIEs/rightsmgmt/default.mspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the user has rights to read the file and has NTFS write permissions anywhere else then they can copy the file to the location where they have write permissions.

What you are trying to achieve requires something to enforce Digital Rights Management - you need both server side and client side parts to enforce what you are trying to do, NTFS wont give it to you it wasn't designed for that sort of control.